# Does an empty Promise rejection needs to be explicitly typed as VOID?

Tags: typescript, promise

Promise rejection returns type **void** by default.

> Promise.reject(reason?: any) => void

Let's say we have a getUser function which returns an User object to pass to a login function for example. So we use a Promise which resolves when we found the user and rejects when no user is found or when an error occurs.

```js
// getUser returns an object or void
getUser(): Promise<object|void> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // user is found
    resolve({ user: user });
    // user is not found or error
    reject();
  });
}

login(): void {
  this.getUser()
    .then((result: object) => {
      // get user here to send back
      this.res.status(200).json({
        user: result['user']
      });
    })
    .catch(() => {
      // don't need to receive data here
      this.res.status(500).json({
        error: 'No login'
      });
    });
}
```

### Is it necessary to explicitly specify the return type as **VOID** in the function return type?

```
getUser(): Promise<object|void>
```

### Or is it enough to only set the return type to object?

```
getUser(): Promise<object>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type parameter to generic `Promise<T>` is the type used to **resolve** the `Promise`. So in this case `Promise<object>` is correct (or even better `Promise<User>` for some `User` type).

Using `Promise<object | void>` is wrong because the `Promise` never resolves with `void`.

Typescript doesn't actually track the type of value used to **reject** a `Promise`. This is because the `Promise` will reject not just when you call `reject()`, but also if an exception is thrown and no attempt is made to track the types of exceptions.

The only other change I would make to your code is to stop using `object` and be explicit about the interface:

```
interface User { user: string }; // Or whatever it really is

getUser(): Promise<User> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // user is found
    resolve({ user: user });
    // user is not found or error
    reject();
  });
}

login(): void {
  this.getUser()
    .then((result: User) => {
      // get user here to send back
      this.res.status(200).json({
        user: result['user']
      });
    })
    .catch(() => {
      // don't need to receive data here
      this.res.status(500).json({
        error: 'No login'
      });
    });
}
```